# WordPress: FS_METHOD 'direct' how much is insecure?

Tags: wordpress, security, filesystems

I have a VPS. I'd like to avoid having to install a FTP server.. How much is WP [FS_METHOD](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) set to `direct` insecure? What system configuration should I avoid? Right now PHP/nginx is run by www-data, which I set to 'root' as secondary group. File permissions are 0775 and owned by *www-data*.

Comment: You should ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ It is more suited there. If you open a new question there let me know. I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: I flagged asking to move the question there.

Comment: I'm just going to have to go out on a limb here and say giving you webserver root level access in group... not a good idea. That alone is asking for trouble, you're basically asking for a directory traversal attack.

Answer (score 1):

as long as you have one (1) site www-data is Ok, but when you have more sites you should never give them the same user, regardless if using the direct FS_METHOD in your wp-config or not.
Why? If one site is hacked all others are/will be too.